# How to prove $\mathcal O_P(C)$ is a DVR for $P$ non-singular?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, valuation-theory

> Let $C$ be an irreducible curve over $\mathbb A^2$ and $P\in C$ a non-singular point. I want to prove that $\mathcal O_P(C)=\{f\in k(C)\mid f=a/b, b(P)\neq 0\}$ is a DVR.

I've already proved that $\mathfrak m_P(C)=\{f\in k(C)\mid f=a/b,a(P)=0, b(P)\neq 0\}$ is the only maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_P(C)$.

In order to prove this I'm using these [equivalences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring). So, to prove what I want I only have to show $\mathcal O_P(C)$ is a PID. Any suggestion how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: @Hoot thank you very much!!!

Comment: I think the way one usually does this is to say that clearly your condition implies that the Zariski cotangent space $\mathfrak{m}_P/\mathfrak{m}_P^2$ of $\mathcal{O}_P$ has dimension $1$ and so $\mathcal{O}_P$ (which has dimension $1$) is a regular local ring, and these are exactly the discrete valuation rings. This is proved in, for example, Prop. 9.2 of Atiyah-Macdonald.

Comment: @Hoot is it not easier just to prove $\mathfrak m_P(C)$ is generated by $X$?

Comment: @Hoot which version of Nakayama's lemma?

Comment: I am just dressing up this statement in terminology and what I believe are useful references. If you just want to show that $\mathfrak{m}$ is principal then Nakayama (Statement #4 on Wikipedia) should do the job.

Comment: @Hoot so in this statement $M=\mathcal O_P(V)$?

Comment: @user42912 What do you mean by a *non-singular point*?

Comment: @user26857 as I said in the comments to Hoot a point $P$ is nonsingular point of $C=V(F)$ if the derivatives $F_X(P)\neq 0$ or $F_Y(P)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well we have to prove that the localization $(K[X,Y]/(F))_{(X-a,Y-b)}$ is a DVR provided $\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}(a,b)\ne 0$ or $\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(a,b)\ne 0$. We have  $$(K[X,Y]/(F))_{(X-a,Y-b)}\simeq K[X,Y]_{(X-a,Y-b)}/(F).$$ 
Now use an automorphism of $K[X,Y]$ ($X\mapsto X+a$, $Y\mapsto Y+b$) and assume $(a,b)=(0,0)$. Suppose $\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(0,0)\ne 0$. Set $R=K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(F)$. We claim that the maximal ideal of $R$ is generated by $x$, the residue class of $X$ modulo $(F)$. All we have to show is $y\in (x)$, that is, $Y\in (X,F)K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}$. Now write $F(X,Y)=YF_0(Y)+XF_1(X,Y)$. Since $\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}(0,0)\ne 0$ it follows $F_0(0)\ne 0$. Then $(X,F)K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}=(X,Y)K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}$ (since $F_0(Y)$ is invertible in $K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}$) and we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you know where can I find the proof of the first isomorphism? thanks again!

Comment: @user42912 This is something usual: $(R/I)_{P/I}\simeq R_P/I_P$, and can be found (as an exercise, I guess) in many textbooks in commutative algebra.

Comment: I'm confused with the generator $(x)$. Is it the set $xR=\{xr\mid r\in R\}$, where $R=K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(F)$?

Comment: @user42912 Right.

Comment: So $(x)=xR=(X+(F))(G+(F))=XG+(F)$, where $G\in k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}$. Thus, $y=Y+(F)\in (x)$ iff $XG+(F)=Y+(F)$ iff $Y\in (X)-(F)$?

Comment: @user42912 Last part should be "iff $Y-XG\in(F)$", equivalently $Y\in(X)+(F)$, and from $(X)+(F)=(X,F)$ you get exactly what I said in my answer.

Comment: Thank you again. You helped me a lot!

Comment: just one question: Why you said "all we have to show is $y\in (x)$"? because $x,y$ generate the maximal ideal?

Comment: @user42912 Exactly.